# NHibernate Attributes Mapping List

Tags: nhibernate, attributes, nhibernate-mapping

I'm a new NHibernate developer. I'm using attributes and not map files and I have configured the application to create the tables automatically.

I Have two classes , Group and User.

Withing the Group class I have a list of users

```
public class Group
{
    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Id(Name = "GroupId")]
    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Generator(Class = "guid")]
    public virtual Guid GroupId { get; set; }
    // What Attributes do I place here
    public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I can't find the right attributes so that there will be two tables that have one to many relation.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
   Ronny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[ManyToMany]](http://www.surcombe.com/nhibernate-1.2/api/html/T_NHibernate_Mapping_Attributes_ManyToManyAttribute.htm), [[OneToMany]](http://www.surcombe.com/nhibernate-1.2/api/html/T_NHibernate_Mapping_Attributes_OneToManyAttribute.htm) or [[ManyToOne]](http://www.surcombe.com/nhibernate-1.2/api/html/T_NHibernate_Mapping_Attributes_ManyToOneAttribute.htm) (those linked docs are fairly useless though) depending on how you want it setup. Probably `[OneToMany]`, and then the same on a User.

You could avoid the pain by using the [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) library instead, if you haven't already tried it.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I'm tried to use  [OneToMany] but the users wasn't saved. Then I tried to add the [List] [Key] [Index] and I got two types of errors.

"Unexpected row count: 0; expected: 1"
"object references an unsaved transient instance..."

Comment: Have you saved the User first? And (for NH2.x) is it inside a transaction?

Comment: thanks, that was the problem :)
Is there a way to tell Hibernate to save the children first automatically?

Comment: Not that I know of, one of the Cascade options may do it though: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/02/NHibernateCascadesTheDifferentBetweenAllAlldeleteorphansAndSaveupdate.aspx